# When I click SearchView, click event doesn't fire (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, click, searchview

I have the following `SearchView`

```
<SearchView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchViewCustomers" />
```

When I click on it I want one of the widgets of the activity to become `visible` and the other one to become `gone` like that:

```
searchView.Click += delegate
{
    customersRecyclerView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    customerDataContainer.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
};
```

But when I run the application and tap on the `searchView` the widgets doesn't become `visible/gone` and when I put break point on `serachView.Click`, program execution never stops there. How to make the widgets visible/gone when I tap on the `searchView` widget?

Comment: i would rather ask you to use the focus event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it is, add a focus change event to the searchview :

```
 searchView.FocusChange += SearchView_FocusChange;
 private void SearchView_FocusChange(object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
              if(searchView.HasFocus)
              {
               //Visibility code
              }
    }
```

**UPDATE :**
First and foremost I would use the Appcompat Searchview for compatibility purpose, Something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
android:clickable="true"
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:id="@+id/searchViewCustomers" />
```

Then I would try using the focus change listener(Same as Above).

If that does not work I would use on query focus change listener something like this:

```
searchView.SetOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new FocusChangeListenerClass());
```

And add the listener class something like this :

```
public class FocusChangeListenerClass : Java.Lang.Object, IOnFocusChangeListener
{
    public void OnFocusChange(Android.Views.View v, bool hasFocus)
    {

    }
}
```

**Update:**

`Activity:`

```
public class ClientsActivity : Activity
{
    .......
    .......
    Android.Widget.SearchView searchView;
    RecyclerView customersRecyclerView;
    ScrollView customerDataContainer;
    .......
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         ........
         ........
         searchView.SetOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new FocusChangeListenerClass(ref customersRecyclerView, ref customerDataContainer));
    }
}
```

`FocusChangeListenerClass.cs:`

```
public class FocusChangeListenerClass : Java.Lang.Object, IOnFocusChangeListener
{
    RecyclerView customersRecyclerView;
    ScrollView customerDataContainer;
    public FocusChangeListenerClass(ref RecyclerView recyclerView, ref ScrollView dataContainer)
    {
        customersRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        customerDataContainer = dataContainer;
    }

    public void OnFocusChange(Android.Views.View v, bool hasFocus)
    {
        if(hasFocus == true)
        {
            customersRecyclerView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            customerDataContainer.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
        else
        {
            customersRecyclerView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            customerDataContainer.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }

}
```

There is no need to change `<SearchView>` to `<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>` in the `.axml` file.

Comment: When I tap on `searchView`,  `SearchView_FocusChange` method doesn't fire up.

Comment: check again please

Comment: where do I put: 
`customersRecyclerView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
 customerDataContainer.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;` using `FocusChangeListenerClass`

Comment: Pass an instance to that class through the constructor and then change the visibility in the other class

Comment: I don't understand "pass an instance" what instance are you reffering to and also "change the visibility in the other class" what class? by the way `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` in `axml` make the program to throw exception on `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ActivityName);` in `OnCreate` method so i made it just `SearchView` again.

Comment: add a breakpoint to onfocus change and check if the view is searchview and if it is make it invisible

Comment: but I don't want to make the `searchView` invisible but other controls

Comment: So pass those controls in the constructor and make them invisible

Comment: I've post an answer to my question containing my solution, please check it out and tell me if you think there is a better solution from the point of view of the quality of the code.

Comment: seems to be good, it would be better if i just update my answer and you mark this one right as it has everything else needed aswell

Comment: ok, but copy exactly my code, so if anyone has the same problem could easily fix it looking at my code.

Comment: Done you can as you please now!